# como instalar controladores en mi maquina virutal?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, controller, maquinas-virtuales

Hola muchas gracias de antemano al que me pueda responder...
Yo estoy utilizando el sistema operativo de Ubuntu 23.10 recientemente lo instale para concentrarme en mis estudios, pero hay algunas cosas que me siento mucho mas comodo haciendolas en windows asi que decidi crear una maquina virtual( cabe destacar que soy nuevo trabajando con una distribucion en linux), la maquina virtual se creo con exito y sin problemas o eso pensaba yo.

Pues resulta que al momento de instalar windows en la maquina virtual me aparece que no tengo contraladores disponibles por la cual no aparecen la particion de disco duro en donde quiero instalar el sistema, ¿que solucion puden darme?

actualmente descargue unos drivers o controladores pero son de windows asi que no se que hacer con ellos pues la mayoria son .exe así que bueno sigo perdido.

Comment: Este sitio es más para preguntas sobre programación. Tal vez sea mejor que preguntes en [ubuntu.se]. Además, es complicado ayudarte con poca información. Sería bueno que incluyas una captura de pantalla del problema. Si solo quieres ejecutar programas de Windows también puedes usar Wine.

Comment: ok gracias por tu sugerencia

Comment: Tienes que instalar los controladores del hipervisor para la máquina virtual. En el caso de VirtualBox se llama Guest Aditions, En VmWare: Vmware Tools, etc... Adicional activar la virtualización desde el Bios de la máquina host para tener mejor rendimiento.